# Is it free to use Amazon Cognito to authenticate users?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to [Amazon Cognito Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/), performing sync operations and/or using sync store space costs money.

But, what if I just want to [use Amazon Cognito to authenticate users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) so that they can access AWS resources (S3 in my case). Is that free? I.e., does authenticating users with Cognito require performing sync operations or using sync store space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Amazon Cognito for authenticating users and retrieving temporary, limited privilege credentials for AWS resources is free.